# ROS natively on the iRobot Create Command Module

Tags: ros, create-robot, cross-compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Does anyone know if it's possible to run ROS natively (i.e. cross compiled) on the Command Module for iRobot Create?

thanks,

Nick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9581/ros-natively-on-the-irobot-create-command-module/) by [hawesie](https://answers.ros.org/users/246/hawesie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 282 on 2011-03-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is not a native release of ROS for 8-bit platforms, so a native executable for the command module is not available.

It is highly unlikely that ROS will ever target a platform that constrained, since most of the focus is on higher-level research.

There are several libraries available for communicating with the iRobot from ROS though.  You can check out everything available on the [Robots for ROS - Roomba](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/Roomba) Page.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @mjcarroll said ROS is not designed to run at the level of 8 bit microcontrollers, communications are abstracted at an IP level which most microcontrollers don't have available.

There are several driver stacks for the iRobot Create [icreate](http://www.ros.org/browse/stack.php?name=icreate),  [turtlebot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_driver), and [irobot_create](http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=irobot_create_2_1) to name a few from [a search of indexed ROS repositories](http://www.ros.org/browse/search.php?q=create).

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1